# Pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions $g_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Let

$$g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = \frac{1}{n}\\
x & \text{if }x = 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ..., \frac{1}{n-1}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I am trying to figure out the pointwise limit of $g_n$, suppose $g_n \to g$. My problem is figuring out what happens when $x = 0$: I am not sure about whether $g(0) = 1$ or $g(0) = 0$.

Clearly, every $g_n(0) = 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, hence it makes no sense that $g(0) = 1$, since if we set $\epsilon < 1$, we always get that $|g_n(0) - 1| = 1 \geq \epsilon$ (proving that the limit is indeed not 1). Thus it must be that $g(0) = 0$. However, the fact that $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ keeps me from being all too sure.

Comment: Be sure.  You already proved you are correct.  Think about the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&,x\ne 0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$It is discontinuous at $0$, but for any $x$ in a deleted neighborhood of $0$ $f=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, by definition, since $0$ is not of the form $1/j$, where $j$ runs over integers, we have by definition of $g_n$ that $g_n(0)=0$, hence denoting by $g$ the pointwise limit of the sequence $(g_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$, we have $g(0)=0$.